# How to update parent ViewModel property from child view model

Tags: wpf, viewmodel, parent-child, communication

I have a view window having tab control with different user controls inside each tab. The window has its own view model and so do each user control. Now how do I update a property of the main window view model from any of the child user control view models ?

Comment: One, share your code to show how its all setup. Two, you're doing this the wrong way. You go from parent to child normally, not the other way. Regardless, can't answer without seeing your setup.

Comment: Although you could technically pass a reference of the parent control to all of the child controls, I think this is generally frowned upon. A better idea might be to fire an event from the child controls that the parent can capture and act upon.

Comment: Well, the easiest way I found to do so was using Events. Create an event at child, and then consume it at parent.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you are instantiating the child view model from Parent ViewModel then you can do it by fireing event from Child View Model and Listening that event on Parent ViewModel and updating the desired property of Parent ViewModel. But if you instantiating your ViewModel from the View i.e your userControl then you need to Create DependencyProperty in UserControl and Bind it to Parent View Model and Child ViewModel Property, but it do have one issue you can bind only one property to target property in xaml and will have to update Child ViewModel Property from the ValueChanged of DependencyProperty. I hope this will give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

My `AddUser` UserControl child:

```
public event EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs> SaveUser;

// Wherever I want that event to be launched I write this:
private void buttonSaveUser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs> handler = SaveUser;
    handler(this, userEventArgs);
}
```

At your `MainWindow.xaml`, once you create your `UserControl` child, suscribe to the event:

```
addUser = new F7AddUser();
addUser.SaveUser += AddUser;
```

And then create your new `AddUser` method (this one has to be at your `MainWindow.xaml`). Take care, as this one comes from an `event`, so arguments have to be the same as the event that launched it:

```
private void AddUser(object o, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Stuff here
}
```

Comment: though event based approach seems to be a good solution I preferred to use the MVVM Light Messenger approach which appeared to be a much cleaner mechanism. Since in my case the VM's are independent of each other(i.e. no VM holds reference of other VM) I chose to use this approach. Please justify my usage of this approach. Would it be a good or bad practice ?

Comment: No, it's not a better usage. It's the way if you're not using MVVM ;)